# How can I automatically find pairs of the same object from two images acquired by different techniques?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have one slide with several objects deposited on top. I have taken two images of the same slide using different techniques ([binocular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ILWX.jpg) and [SEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEYvp.jpg)). This means that the images vary in the imaged area, focus, resolution and perhaps angle of view. Despite these, we can easily identify pairs that belong to the same object, and some which are unpaired due to binary images pre-processing.

For instance, in the **horizontally stacked image** below (see all objects at the higher resolution images [binocular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sXHM.jpg) and [SEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db2zC.jpg)) can be seen that 49 (left) and 71 (right) are the same object, and similarly for the pairs 56-75, 53-72, etc. But some, like object 79 (right), have no respective pair.

[image]

My goal is to automatically detect the pairs that belong to the same object. For this I tried using the code below to, first, resize the images based on four coordinates, which I manually click ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60445099/11493115)), and which belong to the two ends of a known object pair. Secondly, to find similarities between each of the objects using [Match Shapes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html), and sorting them in ascending order, since the pairs closer to 0 are those more similar according to the opencv function.

```
# Import libraries, declare variables and import images

import cv2
import numpy as np
import operator
import os
import math


coordinates = []
match = {}
size = 30

# Match contours and images
thr_sem = cv2.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7GO.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thr_bino = cv2.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ILWX.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Find coordinates for an object pair from both images

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x,",",y)
        coordinates.append([x,y])
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        strXY = str(x)+", "+str(y)
        cv2.putText(thr_bino, strXY, (x,y), font, 3, (255,255,0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Bino thumbnail", thr_bino)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        blue = thr_bino[y, x, 0]
        green = thr_bino[y, x, 1]
        red = thr_bino[y, x, 2]
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        strBGR = str(blue)+", "+str(green)+","+str(red)
        cv2.putText(thr_bino, strBGR, (x,y), font, 3, (0,255,255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Bino thumbnail", thr_bino)
        cv2.imshow("SEM original", thr_sem)
        #calling the mouse click event
        cv2.setMouseCallback("Bino thumbnail", click_event)
        cv2.setMouseCallback("SEM original", click_event)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        #calling the mouse click event
        return coordinates

def call_click():
    cv2.imshow("Bino thumbnail", thr_bino)
    cv2.imshow("SEM original", thr_sem)

    #calling the mouse click event
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Bino thumbnail", click_event)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("SEM original", click_event)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print(coordinates)

# Resize based on coordinates

def resize(coordinates):
    coordinates_list = [item for sublist in coordinates for item in sublist]
    print(coordinates_list)
    small = coordinates_list[:4]
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = tuple(small)
    h_small = y2-y1
    big = coordinates_list[4:]
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = tuple(big)
    h_big = y2-y1
    ratio = h_big/h_small
    h,w = thr_sem.shape
    dim = (int(w/ratio),int(h/ratio))
    resized_sem = cv2.resize(thr_sem, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    return resized_sem

# Find matches based on cv2.matchShapes

def find_and_export_matches(thr_sem, thr_bino):
    resized_sem = resize(coordinates)
    prelim_sem, hier = cv2.findContours(resized_sem, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    prelim_bino, hier = cv2.findContours(thr_bino, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cnts_sem = [contour for contour in prelim_sem if len(contour) > size]
    cnts_bino = [contour for contour in prelim_bino if len(contour) > size]

    for idx, cnt_sem in enumerate(cnts_sem):
        for iddx, cnt_bino in enumerate(cnts_bino):
            ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt_sem,cnt_bino,1,0.0)
            match[f'sem{idx}-bino{iddx}'] = ret
    matches = {k:v for (k,v) in match.items() if v<0.5}
    matches = dict(sorted(matches.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=False))
    print(matches)

# Export the more similar images (e.g. 5 here) 

    for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(list(matches.items())[:5]):
        sem_idx = key.split('-')[0]
        sem_idx = int(re.findall("\d+", sem_idx)[0])
        bino_idx = key.split('-')[1]
        bino_idx = int(re.findall("\d+", bino_idx)[0])
        sem_cnt = cnts_sem[sem_idx]
        bino_cnt = cnts_bino[bino_idx]

        ext_left = tuple(sem_cnt[sem_cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        ext_right = tuple(sem_cnt[sem_cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        ext_top = tuple(sem_cnt[sem_cnt[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        ext_bot = tuple(sem_cnt[sem_cnt[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        margin = int((ext_bot[1] - ext_top[1])/10)
        
        try:
            cropped_sem = thr_sem[ext_top[1]-margin:ext_bot[1]+margin,
             ext_left[0]-margin:ext_right[0]+margin]
            cv2.imwrite(f'./match/{idx}_sem.jpg', cropped_sem)

            ext_left = tuple(bino_cnt[bino_cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
            ext_right = tuple(bino_cnt[bino_cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
            ext_top = tuple(bino_cnt[bino_cnt[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
            ext_bot = tuple(bino_cnt[bino_cnt[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
            margin = int((ext_bot[1] - ext_top[1])/6)

            cropped_bino = thr_bino[ext_top[1]-margin:ext_bot[1]+margin,
             ext_left[0]-margin:ext_right[0]+margin]

            cv2.imwrite(f'./match/{idx}_bino.jpg', cropped_bino)
        except:
            pass

def process():
    call_click()
    find_and_export_matches(thr_sem, thr_bino)

process()
```

Unfortunately, the pairs closer to 0

```
'sem57-bino43': 0.0016109668185579906, 'sem8-bino56': 0.003940798999951367, 'sem83-bino46': 0.004857856469884181, 'sem33-bino20': 0.005706075224340301,'sem67-bino60': 0.0074210065120114965
```

don't belong to the same object:
[image]

[image]

I would appreciate help to detect the pairs that belong to the same object, either by suggesting a technique I did not come across, or by solving the task itself. Something I did not exploit is the fact that the geometrical relations from the particles between one image and the other should be similar. I looked into "image overlaying" processes elsewhere for that purpose but unsuccessfully.

Comment: please present those shape pairs that are listed in your `match` dictionary. I can't find the shapes that belong to `sem8-bino56`

Comment: the higher resolution images referenced in the text contain all the objects outputted in the dictionary. The embedded image was edited to explain the problem. I will edit the question to clarify this. Thanks

Comment: still, point these shapes out. I don't care to find the right number in a picture with dozens of labeled objects, which aren't labeled by an exact order. you expect help. make it as easy as possible to help you.

Comment: I see your point; I have added the pairs of images closer to 0 from the `match` dictionary.

Comment: what are the scores when you match two shapes that _should_ be paired? (except a shape to itself, that better be giving you exactly 0) I can't imagine them doing worse than those mismatched ones.

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestion:**

Unless your example is not representative, the two images are fairly well pre-aligned. So in the first place, you should only look for a matching shape in small neighborhoods of the other image*.

Anyway, only the matching of irregular shapes, in particular very different from round, is reliable. So I would consider a shape similarity metric, and for every shape use the best match but also the second best. If the two matching scores are very close, you can assume that recognition was not safe.

Now sort the parts by decreasing "safeness" and pick the first two, three or four. Using these, you can compute a similarity, affine or homographic transformation that maps one image to the other. This way you can very easily predict the correspondences between any point of both images, and assist further matching or just detect overlaps.

---

*If not, use a scale-invariant matching method over the whole image and proceed as above.